# Jenkins predefined parameters and downstream job

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I have a question for downstream job in jenkins.

I want to use directly the value of a predefined parameters from upstream job in the git parameter of a downstream job.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , just add the parameters to the downstream job. And it will do the trick

Comment: You says that i just need to add a git parameter and i don't need to make configuration ?

Comment: yep , if you have 2 or 3 parameters that you want to use , just add those 3 as parameters to the downstream project.